# After grepping some data into a variable i want to print only the variable is having some data otherwise i dont wabt to print

Tags: bash, shell

```
#! /bin/bash

Var = `anil`

If [ -n "$Var" ] ; then
echo " nn"
else
echo "emp" 
fi
```

This code is not working 
Comming out as if:expressuin syntax

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.   In this case, you will find that your script has problems with both spaces and capitalization.

Comment: @Anil : You don't grep anywhere in your code - aside from the syntax errors in your script.

Comment: You seem to have misspelt `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactical errors in your snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

Var=`grep something somefile`

if [ -n "$Var" ] ; then
echo " nn"
else
echo "emp"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

if "anil" is a string and not a command, it should be like `Var="anil"`. If it's a command it should be `Var=$(anil)`. **In both cases though it should have no spaces**. Also your `if`  **should be lowercase**.

```
#!/bin/bash
Var=`grep -i error anvil.txt`
if [ -n "$Var" ] ; then
echo " nn"
else
echo "emp"
fi
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash


set var =`grep - i error anil.txt`
if [ -n "$Var" ] ; then
echo " not empty"
else
echo "empty"
fi

Comment: @Anil see updated code in answer. **Copy paste exactly** and test.